# Is it possible to get the error message from previous command which failed when the conditional command runs using ||

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling

I have a helper function:

```
function error_exit
{
    /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal ...
    exit 1
}
```

This helper function is used to signal an error. Here is an example of usage:

```
/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s .. || error_exit 'Failed to run cfn-init'
```

The `cfn-init` command takes a lot of parameters which isn't relevant for the question. When the command returns a non-null value and possibly an error message to the error output, I would like to get the error message and include it to the `error_exit` method as a parameter. Is this possible? If not, how would you implement a helper method in bash which makes it possible to get the source error message?

Comment: In the context of CloudFormation's stock templates, from which this looks to derive, also consider setting 'DisableRollback' with `--disable-rollback` in the CLI tools. Also use `cfn-init`'s `-v` flag to get verbose output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can redirect the error output to a file and then retrieve that output:

```
trap "rm -f /tmp/cfn-error.txt" 0 1 2 3 15
/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s ... 2>/tmp/cfn-error.txt ||
    error_exit $(</tmp/cfn-error.txt)
```

You should always clean up your mess, so don't forget to delete any temp files you create.

Comment: any idea how to make it handle unbound variables `set -u;echo $str` ?

Comment: Do you mean handle when the shell would exit because of the `-u` option?  In (da)sh, there is `trap 0`.  In bash, there is `trap ERR`.

Comment: I was working on [this answer/question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146479/30352), yep I ended having to use `trap ERR`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by redirection:

```
# run_cmd 'error message' cmd -foo "${params[@]}"
run_cmd() {
    local e r m=$1
    shift
    exec 6>&1
    e=$("$@" 2>&1 >&6)
    r=$?
    exec 6>&-
    ((r)) || return 0
    error_exit "$m" "$e"
}
```

So you would use:

```
run_cmd 'Failed to run cfn-init' /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s ..
```

The line: e=$("$@" 2>&1 >&6) first directs stderr to stdout, which in the context of $(..) is the output we're capturing. Then stdout is directed to where it originally went when we started the function.

Of course, you can make error_exit additionally take the exit status, and call it with eg: error_exit "$m" "$r" "$e"