# bash 'nounset' on sub-shell/child doesn't force main script to exit, how to workaround that globally?

Tags: bash, error-handling

With this script: *tstNounset.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x 
set -o nounset;set -u

echo `echo $str`
function FUNC1() { echo $str; };export -f FUNC1;bash -c FUNC1
function FUNC2() { set -u;echo $str; };export -f FUNC2;bash -c FUNC2
echo "A - should not reach here?"
echo $str
echo "B - doesn't reach here."
```

I would like to prevent reaching "A", in a global manner, not requiring to check each variable for it.

Also without using `set -e` (as I take care of errors and workaround most already, as many also are only warnings).

I thought if there could have some way to detect **"unbound variable"** happened even from subshell/child, so I could force an exit from that?

I couldn't make things work from [How to have a bash script perform a specific action on errors of _each_ command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101139/how-to-have-a-bash-script-perform-a-specific-action-on-errors-of-each-command) or [How to trigger error using Trap command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79648/how-to-trigger-error-using-trap-command) also. I found this [old question](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/53824-bash-undefined-variable-pipe.html) too.

Answer (score 4):

#### Subshells

There is no way for a subshell to kill the whole script. Under the effect of `set -u`, a subshell has no way to tell its parent “hey, I want you to treat this as a fatal error”. This wouldn't even make sense if `set -u` was in effect in the subshell but not in its parent. All the subshell can do is return a nonzero exit code. It's up to you to handle that exit code in the parent, either manually or through `set -e`.

```
(set -u; …; echo $undefined_variable)
# here $? is nonzero
ret=$?; if [ $ret -ne 0 ]; then exit $ret; fi
```

#### Subprocesses

What you've done here is not a subshell: you're launching another program. That other program happens to be bash, which is also the interpreter that's executing the present script, but it's a coincidence. There is absolutely no reason why a setting in a program invoked by bash would cause bash itself to exit.

```
set +e
bash -c 'do something'
echo "A - should and does reach here"
```

This is no different than if you'd written `perl -e 'use strict; print $barf'` — Perl would die and return a nonzero status but that doesn't cause the bash script to exit (except under `set -e`). Use `set -e` if you want to exit when a subprocess returns a nonzero return code.

Comment: It was right in the first sentence, though the `ret=` thing might be a little much - if I'm one to talk. I just mean that `return/exit` etc automatically return `$?` so it's far more efficient to simply detect failure: `(false) || return` will always return `false`'s parent shell's `$?`.

Comment: I am currently checking if some approach could be done with traps ERR, RETURN and DEBUG, but I am still failing horribly :), as I already use DEBUG one for other thing, I will focus on ERR and RETURN.

Answer (score 0):

My script was badly coded, but it can be fixed:

Look at the 1st, 2nd and 3rd comments:

- 1st A TRAP ERR IS REQUIRED
- 2rd errors that you take care wont be trapped! do not use `if ! ...` will prevent getting return value with $?
- 3nd DO NOT ECHO DIRECTLY, use a intermediary variable so the error can be cautch

tstNounset.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'ErrorHappened;exit 1' ERR #1st A TRAP ERR IS REQUIRED

set -x 
set -o nounset;set -u

#echo `echo $str`
nRet=0;if strA="`echo $str`";then : ;else nRet=$?;echo "Err$nRet";fi #2rd errors that you take care wont be trapped! do not use `if ! ...` will prevent getting return value with $?
echo "0 - should not reach here?"
strA="`echo $str`";echo "$strA" #3nd DO NOT ECHO DIRECTLY, use a intermediary variable so the error can be cautch
echo "1 - should not reach here?"
function FUNC1() { echo $str; };export -f FUNC1;bash -c FUNC1
function FUNC2() { set -u;echo $str; };export -f FUNC2;bash -c FUNC2
echo "A - should not reach here?"
echo $str
echo "B - doesnt reach here."
```